# Why does $\frac {f(n,m-1)} {f(n,m)} = \frac {g(n,m-1)} {g(n,m)} $ here? (Balls and Bins)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, balls-in-bins

Define $f(n,m)$ as returning the amount of ways to throw $n$ **distinguishable** balls into $m$ bins, and $g(n,m)$ as returning the amount of ways to throw $n$ **indistinguishable** balls into $m$ bins. I am wondering whether anyone could conceptually justify why $\frac {f(n,m-1)} {f(n,m)} = \frac {g(n,m-1)} {g(n,m)} $ for any integers $n,m >1$, without just counting the numerators and denominators and using algebraic manipulation to show equivalence. So far, I have tried to think of these functions recursively: seeing combinatorially how  $f(n,m)= f(n-1,m)+ f(n,m-1)$ and $g(n,m) = g(n-1,m-1) + g(n,m-1)$- but I haven't gotten anywhere conceptual with this (There may be an inductive proof with this, but this isn't the type of justification I want here unless it is extremely simple and intuitive).

This problem is of my own construction- the motivation for asking about it was to understand the underlying phenomena in the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795554/why-does-order-matter-here-for-throwing-n-balls-into-n-labelled-bins?noredirect=1#comment10198072_4795554) better.

Comment: The two ratios are *not* equal. You cannot go from computing *probabilities* for balls into bins (where distinguishing the balls is a useful fiction to obtain a uniform probability space) to counting the number of distributions of balls into bins (where we are really counting completely different things).

Comment: @MishaLavrov what would be the way you would justify why the probabilities I linked in the post are the same whether we care or don't care about order?

Comment: Common sense. If one person throws $n$ identical white balls into $n$ bins, and another person first labels the balls with numbers and then throws them into bins, why should this change the probability that the first bin is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we can close this question, the two ratios you ask about are **not** equal.

It is easy to prove that $g(n,m)=m^n$, because each of the $n$ balls must be placed into one of the $m$ bins. This means that
$$
\frac{g(n,m-1)}{g(n,m)}=\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^n
$$
However, using stars and bars, we can show $f(n,m)=\binom{m+n-1}{n}$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{f(n,m-1)}{f(n,m)}=\frac{\binom{m+n-2}{n}}{\binom{m+n-1}{n}}=\frac{m-1}{m+n-1}
$$
Clearly, these two expressions are not equal, for example when $m=2$ and $n=1$.